# is there optimized way to check a string is a numeric and decimal?

Tags: string

I have operator and value as string. When my operator equal to '>' or '<' then i need to ensure the value of the string is numeric or Decimal so it can wrk for both. But i see only isNumeric() ? Any idea

```
String operator = '<';
String value = '3.14';
if(operator.equals('<') && operator.isNumeric() || //Check operator isDecimal)
{
  //Process criteria
}
```

I am thinking in such a way below

```
 try{

    Double value = Decimal.valueOf('1234a');
}
catch(exception ex)
{
    system.debug('Not a number');
    //process further
}
```

But didn't feel ts opt. Suggest me!

Answer (score 1):

Finally end up with the regex as below,

```
public Boolean isValidIntegerOrDecimal(String value) {
    String amtRegEx = '\\d+(\\.\\d+)?';
    Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(amtRegEx);
    Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(value);
    Boolean flag = MyMatcher.matches();
    return flag; 
}

   system.debug(isValidIntegerOrDecimal('0.01'));
```